# Dynamic prototype cells in uitableviewcontroller using storyboards

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uitableview

I've been scratching my head over that problem for two days now and I really can't find why such behavior is happening... This is really starting to make me sick!

I have an iOS app which uses storyboards built with interface builder. The opening view is a TabBarVC owning 2 tabs:

Tab 1 : Navigation Controller -> TableView Controller1 -> TableView Controller2

Tab 2 : Collection View Controller -> Navigation Controller -> TableView Controller3 -> TableView Controller2(yes I meant to write that)

In each one of TableView Controllers 1 and 3, I use dynamic prototyped cells (style = right detail, accessory = disclosure indicator). In the first one, I set a reuse identifier, let's say TableView1Cell. In my implementation of the tableview, I use the following code to return a cell :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableView1Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    SFBottles *bottleAtIndex = [self.dataController getCellarBottleAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:bottleAtIndex.houseName];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:bottleAtIndex.productName];

    return cell;
}
```

...and I use the following code to segue to TableView Controller2 :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowBottleDetails"])
    {
        CellarDetailViewController *detailVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailVC.bottle = [self.dataController getCellarBottleAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
    }
}
```

All of the above works as expected. I do the exact same thing in TableView Controller3 :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableView3Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    SFBottles *bottleAtIndex = [self.bottlesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:bottleAtIndex.houseName];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:bottleAtIndex.productName];

    return cell;
}
```

...and when this view controller gets loaded at runtime, I get the following error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell
>   with identifier TableView3Cell - must register a nib or a class
>   for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

I was however able to clear this error by adding this line to TableView Controller3's viewDidLoad :

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TableView3Cell"];
```

But when I do so, neither the subtitle on the right or the disclosure indicator appear on the displayed cells.

Furthermore, selecting a cell doesn't trigger the segue like it should, even though the code is the same as in TableView Controller1's implementation :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"OverviewListToBottleDetails"])
    {
        CellarDetailViewController *detailVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailVC.bottle = [self.bottlesArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
        detailVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    }
}
```

So, why do 2 look-alike TableView Controllers using the same cells and seguing the same way to the same controller don't behave the same way at all?

I know this is a lot of information, ask your questions and I will answer ASAP.

Thanks!

Comment: In your storyboard, select the prototype cell for table view 3, and check the Identity field in the attribute inspector. Does ti have the right cell identifier there?

Comment: Yes, I verified that about a thousand times! :)

Comment: When using prototype cells in storyboard you must not register them. It deals with it automatically, you just dequeue with the set identifier.

Comment: @MartinStolz Thanks for pointing out the caveat with prototyping cell, I was not able to load content inside tableview cell because of registering the UITableViewCell class with the tableview.