# Must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a default master-detail table view with a [menu](https://github.com/twotoasters/TWTSideMenuViewController). The menu works, but for some reason I get the following error when pressing the '+' button to add another cell in my app:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

I searched for a solution for days

If I add to `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

I don't get the error, but the cells that are added aren't the ones configured in my storyboard, nor do they point to the detail view controller.

I have checked multiple times if the identifier field for the prototype cell has been filled in and is the same as *cellIdentifier.

From what I know it seems of the same nature as the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250563/dynamic-prototype-cells-in-uitableviewcontroller-using-storyboards).

Any help would be appreciated and if you have the time please explain why it's wrong what I did or why certain code should be added.

Requested code (both are default code added by Xcode 5.0.1):

```
// Code to add the button

UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

// Code called when button is pressed:

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
        [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    return cell;
}
```

Also check out the pictures and project files added in the comment

Comment: Is the table view being instantiated from the storyboard or a nib? If not, then it won't know about the prototype cells. Typically, your view controller would be instantiated through a storyboard segue or a `[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier]` and this would in turn instantiate your table view and prototype cells from the storyboard.

Comment: I did everything through the storyboard (except menu code). As I said, I'm new to iOS development, so all I know so far is what apple has in their tutorial and they use the storyboard. Forgive me if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Could you perhaps show some more of your code, particularly the code being called when you tap the + button. Also, as you say you are new to this, could you perhaps go into some detail explaining exactly what you are trying to achieve and what you are expecting the app to do?

Comment: How it is atm: http://imgur.com/szaW9eq,tAoffE6#0
How it's supposed to be like: http://imgur.com/szaW9eq,tAoffE6#1
Project files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/43rd9yifg3ys1vr/YvxYCGL4T_

Comment: I ran your project and confirmed that your storyboard views aren't getting loaded. Haven't figured out why yet, but I wonder if it has something to do with your build configuration. Did you make any changes to your build target?

Comment: Not that I know of. If I did then it would've been by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the following line in `[MAAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunching]`

```
UINavigationController *masterViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[MAMasterViewController new]];
```

with

```
UINavigationController *masterViewController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

When the app reaches `didFinishLaunching`, the root view controller has already been configured from the storyboard (if you look at your storyboard, the root view controller is the one with the arrow pointing to it). Note that this process relies on the `initWithCoder:` initializer.

In `didFinishLaunching` you're discarding this view controller, replacing it with an instance of `TWTSideMenuViewController`, which you've configured with new, non-storyboard instances of `UINavigationController` and `MAMasterViewController`. If you think about it, there's no way for `[MAMasterViewController new]` to know that it should be configured from a particular storyboard element. There is actually an API for instantiating view controllers from the storyboard: `[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]`. But you don't need to do that since it's already been done for you.

So the solution is simple. Just configure `TWTSideMenuViewController` with the existing root view controller `self.window.rootViewController`.

Comment: Thank you! That did it! And explained in a way that I can understand! Thanks